# Android OpenGL Transparent Texture Draws Black

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, transparency

I'm trying to draw transparent textures (text) in my app. Strangely, it works on the newest Nexus 7 and on my second generation Moto X but on the original Nexus 7 the textures are just black. I've got blending enabled and the texture is 512x512 so it's not a power-of-two issue. I'm also just using GL10 which should be supported on everything, right? Any reasons the textures wouldn't work on just this device?

```
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
// text drawn here
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
```

And here's the texture initialization, where I load the texture atlas:

```
public void loadGlyphs(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.text_bitmap);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

Top shows what happens on the old Nexus 7. The bottom picture is a Moto X.

[image: Bad]

[image: Good]

Edit: Here's a complete example. No transparency, doesn't draw anything on the old Nexus 7. If I get rid of the texture stuff it draws the square in white like it should.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView glView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        glView = new TestView(this);
        setContentView(glView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        glView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        glView.onResume();
    }
}
```

TestView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class TestView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private TestRenderer renderer;

    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        renderer = new TestRenderer(context);
        setRenderer(renderer);
    }
}
```

TestRenderer.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class TestRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private FloatBuffer floatBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    private Context context;
    private int[] textures;

    public TestRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        textures = new int[1];
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        floatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 2 * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        floatBuffer.put(-0.5f);
        floatBuffer.put(-0.5f);
        floatBuffer.put(-0.5f);
        floatBuffer.put(0.5f);
        floatBuffer.put(0.5f);
        floatBuffer.put(-0.5f);
        floatBuffer.put(0.5f);
        floatBuffer.put(0.5f);
        floatBuffer.rewind();

        textureBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*2*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(0);
        textureBuffer.put(1);
        textureBuffer.put(0);
        textureBuffer.put(0);
        textureBuffer.put(1);
        textureBuffer.put(1);
        textureBuffer.put(1);
        textureBuffer.put(0);
        textureBuffer.rewind();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.test);
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) w / (float) h, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

        gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, floatBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
}
```

Edit: Here's an example I found online. If I disable GL_TEXTURE_2D I get a white square. If I enable GL_TEXTURE_2D I get nothing.

MainActivity
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

        glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new GlRenderer(this));
        setContentView(glSurfaceView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        glSurfaceView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        glSurfaceView.onPause();
    }

}
```

GlRenderer

```
public class GlRenderer implements Renderer {

    private Square square;
    private Context context;

    public GlRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.square = new Square();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
        square.draw(gl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if(height == 0) {
            height = 1;
        }
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    }
}
```

Square

```
public class Square {

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private float vertices[] = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f
    };

    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    private float texture[] = {
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    private int[] textures = new int[1];

    public Square() {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.test);

        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's the type of texture you're using. Show your texture creation/initialization code.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito added that code

Comment: I was driving at finding out which texture formats you're using, but GLUtils.texImage2d does that internally, so it's not that informative. But, perhaps your drawing code is depending it on being in a specific channel (eg. alpha), and it's putting it in red instead? This was a problem in OpenGL when switching to 3.2 core, because `GL_ALPHA` was deprecated.

Comment: The text atlas is just white text with a transparent background (png

Comment: Try adding GLES20.glGenerateMipMap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

Comment: @samgak that doesn't seem to have done anything. Still blank black textures

Comment: This is way too little information, much can be wrong. Can you try to pinpoint the actual issue. For instance are you sure the textures are even loaded on the GPU? Maybe try a non transparent textures and disable the blend to see if that actually works. Also are you using multiple threads? And maybe force a specific active texture if not done already.

Comment: @MaticOblak added a full example. Even without transparency nothing is drawn. If I disable texturing I get a square like I should. Again, the example works perfectly on the new Nexus 7 and Moto X but fails on the old Nexus 7

Comment: Then it would seem your textures simply are not loaded or not drawn or the texture data is actually not uploaded and is black . It has nothing to do with the transparency or the blending as it seems. Unfortunately even if it works on other devices it might be your bug, not the device's. It can simply work on others after you have forgotten to set a simple value or something... A needle in a haystack.

Comment: sorry, maybe this doesn't answer to your question but, why are you drawing text using a bitmap preconfigured? Why you aren't creating the texture from text direclty? Like drawing text on canvas and converting to texture? I think png's in the drawable directory can mess a bit the rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, I was able to solve the problem on both devices (and presumably all devices) by adding texture wrapping as so:

```
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

I'm not sure why this was necessary for two devices but not the other two, though.

Answer (score 2):

What color format is it your texture is using? Does it match the color format your shader is expecting?

If your color format is RGBA8888 and the shader expects RGB256 you can get problems like this. (It will look for alpha channel information at the wrong place)

Comment: I just logged `GLUtils.getInternalFormat(bitmap)` and got back 6408, which corresponds to GL_RGBA

Comment: Hmmm, can you try opening your texture in GIMP for example and export it in RGB mode? Then try to export in grayscale and see the difference? Some other things I would try: Try to change the precision of your shader to HIGHP float. Try to switch alpha channel from the first bitplane to the last bitplane (or vice versa). Are you using texture compression? Some compression algorhitms does not support alpha channel...

Comment: Switching between RGB and Grayscale hasn't affected it at all. I changed png compression level in GIMP from 9 to 0 with no difference. I also added another example. Interestingly, there's no transparency in that example and the image is still not displayed. Could it just not like GLUtils generating it? Textures work in other apps, so I'm really not sure what the deal is

Comment: I did not mean the compression in GIMP, I meant if you use texture compression when you upload your texture to OpenGL --- Read about it here: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format

Comment: I'm not using any texture compression in the app. It appears to be an issue on older hardware. I just tried it on a Motorola Bionic (XT875) and I'm having the same problem. If I enable GL_TEXTURE_2D I get nothing and if I don't enable I get the white quads. It doesn't look like any of the functions I'm using should cause problems and I'm only using GLES 1.0 so that should be available on any device. Any methods look problematic to you?